# How to modify an image block in Gutenberg WordPress 5?

Tags: theme-development, images, filters, twitter-bootstrap

Adding images to a post with the block editor:

[image]

produces the code figure of:

```
<figure class="wp-block-image">
    <img src="http://localhost:8888/time.png" alt="alt text" class="wp-image-1391"/>
    <figcaption>This is an image test.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

but I'm using Bootstrap 4 and would like to add [Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/) (such as `mt-2`) and to remove the image class `wp-image-1391`, result:

```
<figure class="mt-2">
    <img src="http://localhost:8888/time.png" alt="alt text" class="img-fluid"/>
    <figcaption>This is an image test.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

or be able to modify it to a div:

```
<div class="mt-2">
    <img src="http://localhost:8888/time.png" alt="alt text" class="img-fluid"/>
    <figcaption>This is an image test.</figcaption>
</div>
```

Researching I've found [`get_image_tag_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_image_tag_class/) but testing:

```
function example_add_img_class($class) {
    return $class . ' img-fluid';    
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','example_add_img_class');
```

doesn't work. Reading "[How can I prevent WordPress from adding extra classes to element in the WYSIWYG editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779347/how-can-i-prevent-wordpress-from-adding-extra-classes-to-element-in-the-wysiwyg?rq=1)" I tested:

```
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','__return_empty_string');
```

but doesn't work. I can modify the `<img>` with a `preg_replace` using `the_content` add_filter:

```
function add_image_fluid_class($content) {
    global $post;
    $pattern        = "/<img(.*?)class=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>/i";
    $replacement    = '<img$1class="$2 img-fluid"$3>';
    $content        = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$content);
    return $content;
 }
 add_filter('the_content','add_image_fluid_class');

function img_responsive($content){
    return str_replace('<img class="','<img class="img-responsive ',$content);
}
add_filter('the_content','img_responsive');
```

but I've read that targeting `the_content` with regex can yield mixed results. I could solve the issue with a simple CSS:

```
figure img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
figure figcaption {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:80%;
}
```

but I'd like to understand more of what filters I can use to modify WordPress. How can I add and remove classes and change figure to a div?

Comment: I'd like to know this as well, I have a workaround but going forward I'd like to know how to customize these default blocks.

Comment: I was ready to tear my theme's php code into pieces when I discovered that all images are stretched due to new lazy loading thingy (I guess) +1 for pointing out an easy solution!

Answer (score 5):

After some digging and trial/error I have came up with a couple solutions.  I was looking for a "Gutenberg" solution so I could avoid using `str_replace`.

First, we need to enqueue our JS and include the wp.blocks package

```
// Add to functions.php

function gutenberg_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'myguten-script',
        // get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gutenberg.js', // For Parent Themes
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/gutenberg.js', // For Child Themes
        array('wp-blocks') // Include wp.blocks Package             
    );
}

add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'gutenberg_enqueue');
```

---

Next, I found a couple solutions, the first is probably the best for your specific use-case.

**Method #1**

Use a filter function to override the default class.  Well, in this case we are going to keep the "wp-block-image" class and just add the needed bootstrap class mt-2.  But you could easily add whatever class you wanted.  Add the code below and create a new image block, inspect it to see the figure tag now has the new class.

```
// Add to your JS file

function setBlockCustomClassName(className, blockName) {
    return blockName === 'core/image' ?
        'wp-block-image mt-2' :
        className;
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getBlockDefaultClassName',
    'my-plugin/set-block-custom-class-name',
    setBlockCustomClassName
);
```

---

**Method #2**

Add a setting in the block styles settings in the sidebar to add a class to the image.

```
// Add to your JS file

wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle('core/image', {
    name: 'test-image-class',
    label: 'Test Class'
});
```

[image]

This will add your class but unfortunately Gutenberg appends is-style- before the class, so it results in is-style-test-image-class.  You would have to adjust your CSS accordingly.

---

**Method #3**

Manually adding the class via the Block > Advanced > Additional CSS Class option.  Obviously, the class would need to be added for each image block.

[image]

---

**Note:**  When adding or editing any of the JS above I needed to delete the block, refresh the page and then re-add the block to avoid getting a [block validation error](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/#validation).

**References:**

[Block Style Variations](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#block-style-variations)

[blocks.getBlockDefaultClassName](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getblockdefaultclassname)

Comment: Nice, couldn't we also add the 3. method by using the Advanced settings of the image block to manually append a CSS class to the corresponding image :-)

Comment: haha yes!  I overlooked adding that :)  I will update the answer

Answer (score 4):

Use the `render_block` filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'render_block', 'wrap_my_gallery_block', 10, 2 );

function wrap_my_gallery_block( $block_content, $block ) {

    if ( 'core/gallery' !== $block['blockName'] ) {
        return $block_content;
    }

    $return  = 'my-gallery-block<div class="my-gallery-block">';
    $return .= $block_content;
    $return .= '</div>';

    return $return;
}
```

Works on WP 5.5.

Reference: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/modify-gutenberg-core-block-render-result/#post-11716464

Answer (score 3):

The following answer is a solution for Bootstrap 4 and centering images in a `<figure>` tag.

WordPress generated default:

```
<figure class="wp-block-image">
    <img src="http://localhost:8888/time.png" alt="alt text" class="wp-image-1391"/>
    <figcaption>This is an image test.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Using the [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and `the_content`:

```
function add_image_fluid_class($content) {
    global $post;
    $pattern        = "/<figure class=\"[A-Za-z-]*\"><img (.*?)class=\".*?\"(.*?)><figcaption>(.*?)<\/figcaption><\/figure>/i";
    $replacement    = '<figure class="text-center my-3"><img class="figure-img img-fluid" $1$2><figcaption class="text-muted">$3</figcaption></figure>';
    $content        = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$content);
    return $content;
 }
 add_filter('the_content','add_image_fluid_class');
```

will produce:

```
<figure class="text-center my-3">
    <img class="figure-img img-fluid" src="http://localhost:8888/time.png" alt="alt text" />
    <figcaption class="text-muted">This is an image test.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

The code could be shortened to:

```
function add_image_fluid_class($content) {
    global $post;
    $pattern        = "/<figure class=\"[A-Za-z-]*\"><img (.*?)class=\".*?\"(.*?)><figcaption>/i";
    $replacement    = '<figure class="text-center my-3"><img class="figure-img img-fluid" $1$2><figcaption class="text-muted">';
    $content        = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$content);
    return $content;
 }
 add_filter('the_content','add_image_fluid_class');
```

if you wanted to add `<small>` you could do it as:

```
function add_image_fluid_class($content) {
    global $post;
    $pattern       = "/<figure class=\"[A-Za-z-]*\"><img (.*?)class=\".*?\"(.*?)><figcaption>(.*?)<\/figcaption><\/figure>/i";
    $replacement   = '<figure class="text-center my-3"><img class="figure-img img-fluid" $1$2><figcaption class="text-muted"><small>$3</small></figcaption></figure>';
    $content       = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$content);
    return $content;
 }
 add_filter('the_content','add_image_fluid_class');
```

the backend result is the image block with no align selection:

[image]

post rendered:

[image]

Comment: Good to know this is an option, I ended up finding what is probably the preferred method though, see my answer.

Comment: One can also use the `render_block` filter (PHP) to target a specific block.

Comment: Haven't done that do you an example you can demo?

Comment: I've posted two here recently https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A26350+render_block

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Looks good but will it work in future versions outside the content area for full site editing

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with core block frontend issues are "override core blocks rendering"

example :

```
<?php
function foo_gallery_render( $attributes, $content ) {
    /**
     * Here you find an array with the ids of all 
     * the images that are in your gallery.
     * 
     * for example: 
     * $attributes = [
     *     "ids" => [ 12, 34, 56, 78 ]
     * ]
     *
     * Now have fun querying them,
     * arrangin them and returning your constructed markup!
    */
    return '<h1>Custom rendered gallery</h1>';
}
function foo_register_gallery() {
    register_block_type( 'core/gallery', array(
        'render_callback' => 'foo_gallery_render',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'foo_register_gallery' );
```

This works for all core gutenberg blocks, which means you can take advantage of the great blocks already developped, and arrange their output as you wish.

Reference : https://antistatique.net/en/we/blog/2019/01/29/gutenberg-override-core-blocks-rendering

Comment: Thanks, in my opinion, this is the best solution.