# Assign custom class to post content images

Tags: posts, images, the-content

Is possible to assign a default class to the images that are part of a post content? I have a problem with teh layout, this because the attached images insetred inside a post will break my bootstrap layout. I want to assign a default class so the user when add an image into the content will have the class assigned and the layout will not break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using bootstrap you can add `img-fluid` helper class to images like this.

```
function example_add_img_class( $class ) {
     
    return $class . ' img-fluid';
     
}
 
add_filter( 'get_image_tag_class', 'example_add_img_class' );
```

`get_image_tag_class` filter allows to add custom css class along side WordPress default classes. Read more about the filter [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_image_tag_class/)

Comment: Note that this won't work for the block editor. A solution for that is available here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/326024/39152

Answer (score -1):

I guess you seeking of [get_image_tag_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_image_tag_class/) filter.

Comment: How it's an answer? Edit and add Code example.